# trying to make captcha using rand function in php code is not working

Tags: php

```
               <?php
                       $a=rand(1,10);
                       $b=rand(1,10);

                 ?>

            <form action="1.php" method="get">

             <?php
            echo 'enter the value of<br>';
              echo $a.'+'.$b;
              ?>
              <input type="text" name="sum">
              <input type="submit" name="submit">

                </form>
```

i want to create a captcha using rand function php but this code is not giving me desired result... as on hiting submit it checks the next value of a +b

Comment: Where is your `1.php`?

Comment: this file is 1.php @RussianSoyuzRocket

Comment: You have to save the values you get from rand, if you keep calling rand its going to keep giving you random numbers ...

Answer (score 0):

Either create a separate action file, or add a `if (isset($_GET["submit"]) { }` block to validate the form. Basically your PHP part will then look like:

```
<?php
    $a=rand(1,10);
    $b=rand(1,10);

    if (isset($_GET["submit"]) {
        //this is the validation block
    }

?>
```

You need to submit all three to `1.php` or the validation block: `$a`, `$b` and `sum`. If you are not sure how to submit $a and $b to the action file, just add two more elements to the form:

```
<input type="text" name="operand1" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
<input type="text" name="operand2" value="<?php echo $b; ?>">
```

The comparison `if ($_GET['sum'] == $_GET['operand1'] + $_GET['operand2'])`should be done in `1.php` or in the validation block.

Lastly, it would be sensible to use POST method for this. The GET method uses the URL to store the parameters (url?var1=x&var2=y, etc). The POST method sends the variables as part of HTTP request and they remain invisible to the user (not that it would be perfect from the security point though, there are still ways to read them).

I recommend you start off with a template for a Captcha, instead of making one for yourself. Already there are secure templates available. An example is https://www.phpcaptcha.org.